# Ollama Hallucinations for Simple Questions

Tags: llm, llama-2, hallucination, text-generation

Recently I installed Ollama and started to test its chatting skills.
Unfortunately, so far, the results were very strange.
Basically, I'm getting too much hallucinations even for simple questions like:

- Who was the first black scientist in Brazil?

For this particularly question I tried multiple models from 0.5B~70B parameters and several variants (chat, text, quantization ...).
One of such models even claimed to have reduced hallucinations:

- "Reduced Hallucinations: ensuring more accurate and reliable outputs"
  "In situations where the model lacks a definitive answer, Alfred-40B-1023 is now programmed to state, 'I don’t know' "
  *Source: [Alfred, based on the Falcon 40B model](https://ollama.com/library/alfred)*

Unfortunately, all answers from all models I've tested were complete hallucinations, although often quite convincing.
In several cases the answer was someone famous in Brazil which the AI knew was not black and/or not scientist (ex: the president, a football player, a race pilot, ...).
However, there was no answers like: "I don't know".

I've also tried several different combinations of the following parameters:

- temperature: Makes the model answer more creatively.
- mirostat_tau: Controls the balance between coherence and diversity of the output.
- top_k: Reduces the probability of generating nonsense.
- top_p: Controls the balance between focused and diversity of the output.

Unfortunately, I did not see any influence of this parameters in the chat.
IMHO, it seems that ollama is completely ignoring this parameters.

Therefore, the impression I've got so far is that increasing the model size doesn't translate into more accurate answers.
Instead, it just reinforce the hallucinations to be even more detailed and convincing.

##### Questions

- Is it possible to mitigate hallucinations?
- Is it possible to fine tune the setup in order to reduce hallucinations?
- Is there a model less prone to hallucinations?
- Am I missing something?

---

##### Debug

A couple of models I've tested:

```
NAME                            ID            SIZE
alfred:40b-1023-q4_0            e46325710c52  23 GB
alfred:latest                   e46325710c52  23 GB
gemma:2b                        b50d6c999e59  1.7 GB
llama-pro:latest                fc5c0d744444  4.7 GB
llama2:13b                      d475bf4c50bc  7.4 GB
llama2:70b                      e7f6c06ffef4    38 GB
llama2:latest                   78e26419b446  3.8 GB
llama2:text                     53b394a404fd  3.8 GB
llama2-uncensored:7b-chat-q2_K  74ae83e72254  2.8 GB
orca-mini:latest                2dbd9f439647  2.0 GB
orca2:latest                    ea98cc422de3  3.8 GB
qwen:0.5b                       b5dc5e784f2a  394 MB
qwen:0.5b-chat                  b5dc5e784f2a  394 MB
qwen:0.5b-chat-v1.5-fp16        967f7a3593ba  1.2 GB
qwen:0.5b-chat-v1.5-q4_0        b5dc5e784f2a  394 MB
qwen:0.5b-chat-v1.5-q4_1        1bf15c40f38e  423 MB
qwen:0.5b-chat-v1.5-q5_0        60ea3fa139a6  452 MB
qwen:0.5b-chat-v1.5-q5_1        a60a006869f5  481 MB
qwen:0.5b-chat-v1.5-q8_0        38781999773b  664 MB
qwen:0.5b-text                  f92ac32068ca  394 MB
stablelm-zephyr:latest          0a108dbd846e  1.6 GB
stablelm2:latest                1b81980a10e6  982 MB
tinydolphin:latest              0f9dd11f824c  636 MB
tinyllama:1.1b                  2644915ede35  637 MB
tinyllama:1.1b-chat-v0.6-fp16   a40b38e0c72d  2.2 GB
tinyllama:1.1b-chat-v0.6-q8_0   b939c0e77079  1.2 GB
tinyllama:chat                  2644915ede35  637 MB
tinyllama:latest                2644915ede35  637 MB
```

The Modelfile I used to test different combinations of parameters:

```
FROM tinyllama

# The temperature of the model. [higher is more creative, lower is more coherent]
# Increasing the temperature will make the model answer more creatively. (Default: 0.8)
PARAMETER temperature 0.1

# Controls the balance between coherence and diversity of the output.
# A lower value will result in more focused and coherent text. (Default: 5.0)
PARAMETER mirostat_tau 1.0

# Reduces the probability of generating nonsense.
# A higher value (e.g. 100) will give more diverse answers,
# while a lower value (e.g. 10) will be more conservative. (Default: 40)
PARAMETER top_k 10

# Works together with top-k. A higher value (e.g., 0.95) will lead to more
# diverse text, while a lower value (e.g., 0.5) will generate more focused and
# conservative text. (Default: 0.9)
PARAMETER top_p 0.5
```

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I am running into similar problems. I also tried making the prompt explicitly request to not make up information and things like that.

Answer (score 3):

Hallucinations are an inevitable consequence of how LLMs work.  An LLM is a hugely sophisticated prediction engine, trained to predict the most probable continuation of the input based on the analysis of vast amounts of text.

However, an LLM does not actually know anything in the sense that humans think of it.  In order to get one to answer a question with an "I don't know", it needs to encounter that question-answer pair (or something similar) in its training data.  For example, most LLMs, when asked to solve the Halting Problem (a famously unsolvable problem in computer science), will correctly respond that it's unsolvable, because that's the most probable continuation of "What is the solution to the Halting Problem?"  But when presented with a question not found in the training data, the LLM will extrapolate an answer from similar-looking questions that *are* in the training data, and will often be wrong, because text extrapolation (the thing an LLM does) isn't the same as knowledge extrapolation (what you're expecting it to do).

Comment: > "In situations where the model lacks a definitive answer, Alfred-40B-1023 is now programmed to state, 'I don’t know' ", _Source: Ollama Model Alfred_ . Mind to reconcile?

Comment: @JeronBaffom, they say nothing about *how* they did that, and the model itself appears to be a standard generative LLM.  The most likely explanation is that they simply fine-tuned Falcon-40B with a huge list of things that it doesn't know.